# Need to change the html values via css as metioned below. I am using wordpress so its not good to edit core files

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Need to change the html values via css as metioned below.
I am using wordpress so its not good to edit core files.

```
<a class="slide-btn smoth-scroll" href="#About">Get started</a><a class="slide-btn other-btn smoth-scroll" href="#contact">contact us</a>
```

The above html to be changed to by using css alone.

```
<a class="slide-btn smoth-scroll" href="#About">Free Estimate</a><a class="slide-btn other-btn smoth-scroll" href="#contact">contact us</a>
```

Comment: what do you want to change?

Comment: "Need to change the html values via css" - I'm not sure if you know what are you talking about…

Comment: so you want to change Get started text to Free Estimate??..If yes.. You can not change it by css.you need to use jquery for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recomended but you can try this

```
.slide-btn {
 display:none;
}

.slide-btn :after{
 content: "Free Estimate";   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by using jquery

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("a[href='#About']").text('Free Estimate');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="slide-btn smoth-scroll" href="#About">Get started</a><a class="slide-btn other-btn smoth-scroll" href="#contact">contact us</a>
```